# Cocos2d: How to play a video in the background of a CCLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ccvideoplayer

I want the video play in the background, and the text label in the front, run the following code, video is playing, but text label does not show!

```
-(id) init {
    if(!(self=[super init])) {
        return nil;
    }

    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // MP4
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4v"]];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.height, size.width);
    [viewController.view  addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [viewController.view  sendSubviewToBack:moviePlayer.view];

    // create and initialize a Label
    CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
    label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
    [self addChild: label];

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

First in AppDelegate.m replace kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 with kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, Second, as the following code, the last 4 lines is important:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];

[_moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)];
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
_moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
_moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);

UIView* glView = [CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView; // attention
[glView.superview insertSubview:_moviePlayer.view atIndex:0]; // attention
glView.opaque = NO; // attention
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // attention
```

Answer (score 1):

CCVideo player in one of the best options to play video in cocos2D project

```
[CCVideoPlayer setDelegate: self];
[CCVideoPlayer playMovieWithFile: @"bait.m4v"];
```

Comment: Use CCVideoPlayer how to send the CCVideoPlayer view to background?